# Display summery of likes from facebook page and web site

Tags: facebook

I want to integrate the number of likes that I have in my website with the number of likes that I have in my facebook application, so for example if user clicks on my site like button and another user click on my facebook page like, the total likes that I will see on both the applications(site and facebook) will be 2.
My question is is this possible  at all or thous are 2 separate objects and it is not possible to sum there likes

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can find the like count of your website by running the following [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) query:

`SELECT like_count FROM link_stat WHERE url="yourwebsiteurl"`

Then, you can get the like count of your app in one of two ways. If the like button for your app points to its apps.facebook.com address, use the same query as above, with its app URL instead of your website URL.

If the likes for your app are from a Page associated with the app then you should make a Graph API call to:

`https://graph.facebook.com/YOURPAGEID?fields=likes`

This will give you the like count for each object, now you just need to sum them.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I don't mean to count the number of clicks, just display the same number both in the Facebook page and on the website page. any how I managed to do it by pointing the like button href parameter to the Facebook application. in that way I have now the same count on both the web site and the Facebook page

Comment: @wintersun Can you explain more on how you were able to "point the like button href parameter to the Facebook application"? Thanks.